# Why my github site only show README file?

Tags: r, git, github, r-markdown

I learn to make a simple website using RMarkdown and GitHub and made basic files like _site.yml; index.Rmd; and about.Rmd;

However, my site only show README.md instead of index.html.

Can somebody help me to check it?

https://github.com/isaid-hi/isaid-hi.github.io

http://www.isaid-hi.xyz/

Comment: Is it because there is no gh-pages branch?

Comment: I don't know, I can't find gh-pages branch in the setting. Only main branch.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know, I can't find gh-pages branch in the setting. Only main branch.

Then you need to double-check your [publication source setting](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site) in order to select a folder (in your case `_site`) for your publishing source.

[image: https://docs.github.com/assets/images/help/pages/publishing-source-folder-drop-down.png]

Comment: Actually, I'm not really sure what did you mean. if you mean the location of the _site.yml file, I save _site.yml in the /root folder (not in any folder). I used main branch as publicing source. Should I change to none?

Comment: /root in the image is just an example, replace it with the folder where you generate your site.

Comment: I cant find option other than /(root) and /docs (if that what you mean). Can you please help me again?

Comment: Strange, I thought you now could chose your own folder. Just for testing, could you generate the site in the docs folder?

Comment: Nope. I saw the example https://github.com/zabore/zabore.github.io and https://github.com/privefl/privefl.github.io/blob/master/_site.yml didn/t include _site folder.

Comment: I really suspicious to _site folder